# Java - How to check if a 13 digit isbn number is valid

Tags: java

I need to write a program that allows the user to enter a 13-digit ISBN as a single integer.

The program should then determine and show whether the number is valid according to the formula above. It also needs to print an error message if the user tries to enter a number longer than 13 digits. 
Below is the code I am working on.

I'm new to java and I don't understand where it went wrong. I also don't seem to figure out how to get the length of a long variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ISBNChecker{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        long isbnNumber;
        long isbnTotal;
        long x;

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        isbnNumber = scnr.nextLong();           

        while (isbnNumber > 0) {
            x = isbnNumber % 10;
            isbnTotal = total + x;
            isbnNumber = isbnNumber / 10;

            x = isbnNumber % 10;
            isbnTotal = total + (3 * x);
            isbnNumber = isbnNumber / 10;
        }

        if (isbnTotal % 10 = 0) {
            System.out.println("Number is valid!");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Number is invalid.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what errors do you get, and what line does it tell you the error is on?

Comment: Why immediately read a long when you can read it as a string, check its length right then, and then parse it?

Comment: Reading as String solves multiple problems since you're going to have to multiply each numeral by its position in the number and sum all those values before using the modulus operator to check validity. This means you can do everything in a single loop of known duration (think for, not while).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Fix your (own) current code

In your original code, you have a couple of tiny errors:

```
isbnTotal = total + x;
```

`total` is not declared anywhere, and `isbnTotal` is not initialized.

```
if (isbnTotal % 10 = 0) {
```

You need to compare with double `=`, a single one is for assignation, double `==` is for comparison.

---

## Separate your code into modules to improve it

> ... determine and show whether the number is valid according to the formula above.

I think that you forgot to write the formula, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-13_check_digit_calculation), is this one:

[image]

So, you need to check if the sum of all digits multiplied by their weight (alternating 1 and 3) is a multiple of 10.

So, first of all we need to get the sum of all digits and multiply each digit by 1 or 3 alternating (backwards as we're gonna be using the `modulo` operator).

So, we need something like this:

```
private static int getSum(long isbn) {
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    do {
        sum += count % 2 == 0 ? isbn % 10 : 3 * (isbn % 10);
        count++;
        isbn /= 10;
    } while (isbn > 0);
    return sum;
}
```

Let me explain what the above code does, is make use of the [ternary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator (CTRL-F on the page to read about it), to determine if we need to multiply by 1 or 3, in the formula it starts with 1, so the easiest way to do it is by checking if the current index is even or odd, if even, multiply by 1, otherwise multiply by 3, and adds that number to the sum.

Then it divides the current number by 10.

Then all we have to do is check if the sum of all digits multiplied by their respective weights is a multiple of 10.

```
private static boolean isAValidISBN(long isbn) {
    return getSum(isbn) % 10 == 0;
}
```

And just before that, if the given number doesn't have 13 digits, we say that it isn't.

So, in the end our program should be something like:

```
public class ISBNChecker {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String isbnNumber = "978030640615";
        if (isbnNumber.length() != 13) {
            System.out.println("ISBN Number is invalid");
            return;
        }

        if (isAValidISBN(Long.parseLong(isbnNumber))) {
            System.out.println(isbnNumber + " is a valid ISBN");
        } else {
            System.out.println(isbnNumber + " is not a valid ISBN");
        }
    }

    private static int getSum(long isbn) {
        int count = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        do {
            sum += count % 2 == 0 ? isbn % 10 : 3 * (isbn % 10);
            count++;
            isbn /= 10;
        } while (isbn > 0);
        return sum;
    }

    private static boolean isAValidISBN(long isbn) {
        return getSum(isbn) % 10 == 0;
    }
}
```

And if we take the Wikipedia value, we get this output:

```
9780306406157 is a valid ISBN
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what do you mean with:

> according to the formula above.

What formula do you mean? And Second, to get the length of an long or integer just do:

```
int length = ("" + isbnNumber).length()
```

And btw, when you are doing an `if` statement do "==" instead of "=".

```
if (isbnTotal % 10 = 0) {
```

…should be:

```
if (isbnTotal % 10 == 0) {
```

Or better, reverse so compiler would have caught your typo.

```
if (0 == isbnTotal % 10) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question clearly, but I suppose what you want to do is validate if the number provided by the user has 13 digits or not, you could do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            String userNumber;  
            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter ISBN number, 13 digit");

            userNumber = scnr.nextLine();

/*regular expression to verify that it contains only 13 digits*/
            if(userNumber.matches("^[0-9]{13}$")) {  
                System.out.println("Number is valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Number is invalid");
            }
    }
```